# subsetting and performing calculations on time series data, avoiding loops

Tags: r, time-series, subset

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following without looping. I have a melted dataset of time, study site, and flow that looks like:

> datetime   site    flow
>   6/1/2009 00:00  EBT NA
>   6/2/2009 01:00  EBT NA
>   6/3/2009 02:00  EBT 0.1
>   6/4/2009 03:00  EBT NA
>   6/5/2009 04:00  EBT NA
>   6/1/2009 00:00  MUT 0.4
>   6/2/2009 01:00  MUT 0.3
>   6/3/2009 02:00  MUT 0.2
>   6/4/2009 03:00  MUT NA
>   6/5/2009 04:00  MUT NA

I need to subset this by site, and then for periods when there are at least two subsequent flow measurements I need to perform a couple of calculations, *for example the mean of the current and previous measurement.

The trick is that I need to perform the average on each set of consecutive measurements, i.e. if there are three in a row for each of the latter two I need the average of that measurement and the previous one. I've added a goal column to the sample dataframe with the results I'd like to get.*

I'd like to end up with a similar looking dataframe with the datetime, site, and result of the calculation. There is a full time series for each site.

Thanks for any help!

data generator:

```
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1167627600, 1167717600, 
1167807600, 1167897600, 1167987600, 1167627600, 1167717600, 1167807600, 
1167897600, 1167987600, 1168077600, 1168167600, 1168257600, 1168347600, 
1168437600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), site = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("EBT", 
"MUT"), class = "factor"), flow = c(NA, 0.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0.4, 0.2, NA, NA, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, NA, NA), goal = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.3, NA, NA, NA, 0.3, 0.15, NA, NA)), .Names = c("datetime", 
"site", "flow", "goal"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide the resulting data set you're looking for?  You can do this easily with many tools in R... `library(data.table); s=data.table(sample); s[, mean(flow), by=site]`...

Comment: Edited question to be clearer and add sample output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will separate your dataframe by `site` and then filter only rows that have two or more consecutive non-NA values in `flow`:

```
by(sample, sample$site, function(d) d[with(rle(!is.na(d$flow)), rep(values & lengths>=2, lengths)),])
```

You can then work on the function inside to do your calculations as needed.

For instance, if you want to add the mean as a new column (assuming you want `NA` when not defined) you can use this:

```
f <- function(d)
{
    x <- with(rle(!is.na(d$flow)), rep(values & lengths>=2, lengths))

    within(d, {avg <- NA; avg[x] <- mean(d[x,"flow"])})
}

b <- by(sample, sample$site, f)

Reduce(rbind, b)
```

Result:

```
              datetime site flow avg
1  2009-06-01 01:00:00  EBT   NA  NA
2  2009-06-02 02:00:00  EBT   NA  NA
3  2009-06-03 03:00:00  EBT  0.1  NA
4  2009-06-04 04:00:00  EBT   NA  NA
5  2009-06-05 05:00:00  EBT   NA  NA
6  2009-06-01 01:00:00  MUT  0.4 0.3
7  2009-06-02 02:00:00  MUT  0.3 0.3
8  2009-06-03 03:00:00  MUT  0.2 0.3
9  2009-06-04 04:00:00  MUT   NA  NA
10 2009-06-05 05:00:00  MUT   NA  NA
```

---

EDIT: To get the mean between the current flow measure and the previous one, you can use this:

```
f <- function(d)
{
    within(d, avg <- (flow+c(NA,head(flow,-1)))/2)
}

Reduce(rbind, by(sample, sample$site, f))
```

Note that cases with a single measure are automatically set to `NA`. New result:

```
              datetime site flow goal  avg
1  2007-01-01 03:00:00  EBT   NA   NA   NA
2  2007-01-02 04:00:00  EBT  0.1   NA   NA
3  2007-01-03 05:00:00  EBT   NA   NA   NA
4  2007-01-04 06:00:00  EBT   NA   NA   NA
5  2007-01-05 07:00:00  EBT   NA   NA   NA
6  2007-01-01 03:00:00  MUT   NA   NA   NA
7  2007-01-02 04:00:00  MUT  0.4   NA   NA
8  2007-01-03 05:00:00  MUT  0.2 0.30 0.30
9  2007-01-04 06:00:00  MUT   NA   NA   NA
10 2007-01-05 07:00:00  MUT   NA   NA   NA
11 2007-01-06 08:00:00  MUT  0.4   NA   NA
12 2007-01-07 09:00:00  MUT  0.2 0.30 0.30
13 2007-01-08 10:00:00  MUT  0.1 0.15 0.15
14 2007-01-09 11:00:00  MUT   NA   NA   NA
15 2007-01-10 12:00:00  MUT   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Ferdinand, this is very close. Thanks! However, this calculates the average across all flows per site that meet the criteria. What I should have been clearer about is that I need to perform the calculation on each set. I've edited the question to be clearer and added some data to the sample set, along with what output I'm shooting for. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Plyr functions are a good way to split apart dataframes by certain variables, which is what you need to do.

I thought of two ways to handle intervals on a vector: first with vector multiplication (for the mean of the data), and second with vectorizing a function (for generating the labels). They're both doing pretty much the same thing, though.

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
library(lubridate)

meanBetween <- function(x){
  l <- length(x)
  diag(outer(x[1:(l-1)], x[2:l], "+"))/2
}

output <- ddply(sample, .(site), function(df){
  df <- df[order(df$datetime, decreasing=FALSE), ]
  result <- meanBetween(df$flow)
  names(result) <- Reduce(c, (mapply(as.interval,
                                     df$datetime[-1],
                                     df$datetime[1:(length(df$datetime)-1)],
                                     SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))
  result
})

melt(output) # to make it look nicer
```